# Why Executing Stored Procedure Causes It To Be Created

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I have added to Azure SQL Server. Every time I execute the procedure either by means of an Azure Logic App or in SSMS, it performs a create when I view the running queries.

Is this normal?

Stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [FHQGY].[GetCommentsToEventServiceBus]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Results TABLE
    (
        CommentId INT NOT NULL,
        CallId VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
        JsonMessage VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL
    )   

    INSERT INTO @Results (CommentId, CallId, JsonMessage)
        SELECT TOP(500)
            comments.COMMENT_ID,
            comments.CALL_ID,
            CONCAT('{',
                        '"event":"commentadded"', ',',
                        '"callId":"', calls.CALL_ID, '"', ',',
                        '"commentId":', comments.COMMENT_ID, ',',
                        '"testCall":', (CASE WHEN calls.TEST_FLAG = 'Y' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END), ',',
                        '"useProd":', (CASE WHEN DB_NAME() = 'ProdDB' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END), ',',
                        '"submittedDateTime":"', FORMAT(dbo.GetDateCDT(GETUTCDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ'), '"', ',',
                        '"overrideEmailAddress":""',
                    '}')
        FROM 
            FHQGY.AD_CC_CALL_COMMENTS comments
        JOIN 
            FHQGY.AD_CC_CALLS calls ON comments.CALL_ID = calls.CALL_ID
        WHERE 
            1 = 1
            AND (comments.SENT_TO_EVENT_BUS = 0 OR comments.SENT_TO_EVENT_BUS IS NULL)
        ORDER BY 
            comments.ADD_TSTAMP ASC

    SELECT DISTINCT
        CommentId,
        CallId,
        JsonMessage
    FROM 
        @Results
END
```

[image: view running queries]

Comment: You have a table variable -- it has to create it.

Comment: Why `WHERE 1=1`? When does `1` not equal `1`?

Comment: Hogan - I removed the table variable and it is still trying to create the procedure each time.

Comment: Larnu - Makes it easier to debug different features as each relevant filter starts with an "and"

Comment: In a  test environment, I suppose, but why in production?

Comment: Larnu - Does it affect performance?

Comment: That script is not executing a stored procedure. It's altering an existing one. To execute it use `EXEC [FHQGY].[GetCommentsToEventServiceBus]`

Comment: Nick - That's how I'm executing the stored procedure